# Find minimum precision setting

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I am using `FindMinimum` command to find a local minimum of an object function. My code is below

```
FindMinimum[obj[h],{h,h_init},
Method -> "QuasiNewton",
Gradient->grad[h]];
```

All the calculations are performed numerically. However, there is an precision error

```
FindMinimum::sdprec: Line search unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function value with MachinePrecision digit precision.
```

I don't understand this error because Machine number can represent number as small as `$MinMachineNumber=2.22507*10^-308` in my computer. My computation has no chance to involve such a small number. Why this error pops up? Is it possible to prevent such error in general? Because my object function is complicated, using arbitrary precision number is very slow.
If not, i.e. I have to use arbitrary precision number by setting `WorkingPrecision`, do I need to reset "Precision" of any number in my code to be consistent with the `WorkingPrecision` setting inside `FindMinimum`? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you did not actually set any other options except `Method` and `Gradient`, `FindMinimum[]` is saying that the line search it is doing as part of the optimization is unable to fully satisfy the convergence criteria for your optimization. Why this might happen depends on what function you have.

Comment: It is also worth noting that while extremely high precision can be achieved near 0 with machine precision numbers, the precision at larger numbers is rather less. On my machine the highest precision achievable around 1.0 is on the order of `2.22045*10^-16`. The error on machine precision numbers is proportional to the number itself.

Comment: @eyorble Thanks for your comments! So, the error for machine precision number is proportional to the number itself. If for 1.0, the error is 2.22045*10^-16. The what the error would be for extremely small number such as 1.0*10^-100. Is there some formula that I can evaluate such error for machine precision number? I feel very confused about these numerical errors and precision thing even after reading the relevant Wolfram document. Is there some good reference to learn such things? Thanks!

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less Thank you for your comments! My object function is an extremely complicated function. I have no ideal to test its behavior during minimization. Maybe that is the reason.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, I just created a C program and measured what the epsilon between 1.0 and the immediately following double is. The problem with the errors is that they're dependent on the intermediate value, not the final value. So if any number in the process is larger than 1.0, you'll probably end up with an error on the order of 10^-16 that will never cancel out quite right. Unless every error matches up perfectly the magnitude of the error can't be decreased that much.

Comment: @eyorble I see. So, the error of the final result, as a double number,  depends on all intermediate numbers. However, for number other than 1.0, we have no good way to estimate the epsilon. So, it is difficult to evaluate the error for the final number.